# Where to set Tomcat project's webservices url?

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat7, tomcat

If I go to http://web-server:port/myProj/services my web services are listed there. However, I need them to be available at http://myProj:port/myProj/services (for example if myProj is called kylem and on the default port I'd see my services listed at http://kylem:8080/kylem/services). How do I change it to get the url I just mentioned?

edit:

Hoping someone can provide some advice for more places to look. As described below, someone had previously set up Apache Tomcat so that the url I described above already (http://projName/..) works. But I cannot figure out how/why it works. The only  tag in my Tomcat/conf/server.xml file just has

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

It also has a  tag in it, but that seems unrelated. Is there anything else that could possibly be set up to allow the use of http://projName instead of http://server-name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set them as aliases to the current host in `server.xml`

```
<Host name="foo.com" appBase="/var/www/app" 
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
         <Alias>bar.com</Alias>
         <Alias>baz.com</Alias>
</Host>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the server.xml in tomcat/conf? Because I don't see it there, although I should? (... when Tomcat 7 is running, I can already go to the http://kylem:8080/kylem/services url that I mentioned. When Tomcat is not running, I cannot go there and see my services. Somebody else set up the 'url aliasing' though, I'm trying to figure out WHERE it is set up...). Thanks a lot for your help.